# Building Organizational chart using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have JSON data which come from server.

I want to display organization chart in the HTML file in the below format:

```
                       CEO
                        |
                        |
            #Manager             #Manager
```

I am using Dojo. I find [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/interactive-diagrams-dojo-diagrammer/index.html) extremely useful. I want to build exactly the same thing.

I am not able to find required dojo files in there site. So it could be proprietary to IBM.

I tried [this link](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html), but I do not find it useful.

Can someone please tell me how should I do it Using dojo or any other frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [google org charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html) . fairly easy to use it think.

Comment: Can one use this offline? Eg. in an enterprise network without access to the Internet?

Answer (score 3):

you can use **[Basic Primitives Diagrams](https://www.basicprimitives.com/)**

[image]

Which has various diagrams and optional format and is also open source,
it's client side JavaScript layout and rendering and no dependencies on 3rd party libraries.

It is also possible to try it online [here](https://www.basicprimitives.com/usecases/firstorganizationalchart)

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to offer jquery solution. As for which is the most easy to use, it all depends on your practical trying results. 
The following snapshot shows the tree-like hierarchy created by jquery plugin [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart)

[image: snapshot]

If you have not svg, canvas or flex background, maybe this pure dom solution will be your favorite :)